# How to use Nginx with different physical machines?

Tags: nginx, networking, centos, reverse-proxy

I have many VMs running with different web servers and such. I want to be able to use the SSL port on more than one machine, which is where Nginx comes in. 
I have looked and dug, and I do not understand if you can achieve using different physical VMs with Nginx.

I have a:

- CentOS machine running Apache as my main (no virtual hosts) website. IP of 10.40.1.12 internally, reachable at kodysalak.com
- Windows Server 2016 with exchange on it. IP of 10.40.1.17 internally, reachable at mail.kodysalak.com
- Windows Server 2016 with Spiceworks' HelpDesk software (Apache). IP of 10.40.1.14 internally, reachable at help.kodysalak.com

Those are the hosts that use 80/443. I have a separate CentOS machine running Nginx with no configuration done with it. IP of 10.40.1.18. 
Any help would be SO helpful, of course.

Comment: This might be more appropriate for [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

nginx's `proxy_pass` (reverse proxy) and `server_name` (vhost).

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass

Portforwarding from Firewall, then with the HTTP Header "Host" (SSL/TLS: SNI) aka virtual hosting.

**Edit:**

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.kodysalak.com kodysalak.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://10.40.1.12;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name mail.kodysalak.com owa.kodysalak.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://10.40.1.17;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name help.kodysalak.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://10.40.1.14;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not going to like me, but most of that is jibberish. Here's what I have. https://pastebin.com/1Fs1ckEd